# Azure SQL Query Performance Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, sqlperformance

I'm running a query against an Azure SQL DB...

```
select Id
from Table1
  WHERE ([Table1].[CustomFieldString2] IS NULL) AND
        (N'New' = [Table1].[CustomFieldString7]) AND (0 = [Table1].[Deleted])
```

This query runs fast roughly 300ms...

As soon as I add another column to my select (bool) as in

```
Select Id, IsActive
```

my query is super slow (minutes)

This doesn't make any sense...

Was wondering if anyone knew what this could be

Comment: Not alot to go on here. Are there indices on the fields in the filter? If so, then SQL Azure doesn't need to go to the database to get the id in the first query since it is the primary key and the index itself would have a copy of this value.

Comment: Please  explain  what is N'New '

Comment: N'New' makes the 'New' literal screen a unicode string as opposed to an ascii string

Comment: @MikeS All the columns that are filtered have indexes.  You are correct in that the column added IsActive is not part of the index, so it does have to go to get by id, and this is a clustered index so it should be fast. Additionally this query is only retrieving approximately 300 records

Answer (score 1):

In Summary, when you add columns which are not part of index to the `select` then SQL can't choose the same execution plan.

If SQL estimates there are fewer rows, then it will opt to use nested lookups in the execution plan. This can take more time, if estimates are wrong.

If there are more rows or key lookup cost crosses some threshold, SQL may then decide that a scan of the table is likely to be more efficient.

Try adding `isactive` to the included column list, if the query performance is not acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

You query constructure is important of course but Azure is naturally slow. Is is using cloud systems so it is not so fast (I supposed using free version.)  ı have not seen anyone pleasure about azure velocity. (in low prices)